# How can I see the size a package will require to download?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm on a restricted bandwidth and would like to see how much an `opam install some-package` would require to download. Any such option with opam?

Comment: There is no such option.  OPAM repository itself has no knowledge of package sizes.  (This does not prevent you from writing such a tool of course.)

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but you might be interested in `opam-bundle` which is supposed (not tested personally ;-) to let you, or someone you know with an unrestricted internet access, create an archive containing all the necessary dependencies for installing a given opam package.

Comment: @camlspotter But OPAM downloads the necessary files? So during that process, it should be fairly easy to show the file size of the source package.

Comment: @Virgile Yes, this is a solution that could work if I login to my virtual server and download from there. Thank you!

Comment: @OlleHärstedt, OPAM CI downloads the source archive, so it once knows the size of the archive.  However, the repository has no size info.